AWS Glue Crawler converting '.' in parquet file to '_' in table
AWS Glue crawler is creating a table in the Data Catalog differently than parquet file. AWS Glue Crawler converting '.' in parquet file to '_' in table
for example:
parquet file name: schema.tablename
table name: schema_tablename
expected table name: schema.tablename
Is there any Glue crawler setting or properties doing it? Please advise.

I think this is not possible, if you refer to the following documentation on how crawlers work (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-crawler.html#crawler-running).
It states the following:

The crawler generates the names for the tables that it creates. The
names of the tables that are stored in the AWS Glue Data Catalog
follow these rules:"

Only alphanumeric characters and underscore (_) are allowed.


In regards to how you are referring/using the term "schema", which I think you are refeering to database schema, AWS Glue doesn't work like that, if you wanted to include/allocate multiple tables within one collection, it would be within one AWS Glue database.
If you wanted to have a separation/grouping of multiple tables within one DATABASE, you will need to create this beforehand, and point your crawler to create the table within this, and as for the name of the table, you can remove the "schema" prefix and just use the name of the table.
